# Matrix or random binomial values

Tags: r, random

I'd like to generate a N by n matrix, with colum having different p values:

```
N=100000
n=100
p= seq(0.005,0.995,.01)

xsim=rbinom(N, size = n, prob = p)
ysim=rbinom(N, size = n, prob = p)
```

This does not appear to have the correct dimmensions want each row to have a different p. Is there a wa y to do this with apply or otherwise. thanks

Comment: What dimensions? I mean where do you construct a matrix? And you say _"with colum having different p values"_ in one sentence and _" want each row to have a different p"_ in another. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sapply(p, rbinom, n = N, size = n)
```

`rbinom` doesn't take a vector argument in `p`.